# Rally 2.0 SDK - Query filtering only returns 200 results

Tags: rally

I'm trying to get more than 200 elements in my queries. So, I've modified the limit of results that the query should return according to [this documentation](http://developer.help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p5/doc/#!/guide/appsdk_20_data_stores), but this is not working. Any idea?

I'm trying the following:

```
var tasksWithActualsQuery = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', 
{
    model: 'Task',
    limit: Infinity,
    fetch: ['CreationDate', 'Actuals'],
    filters: 
    [     
        {
            property: 'CreationDate',
            operator: '<',
            value: 'LastMonth'
        }
    ]
});

tasksWithActualsQuery.load({
    callback: function(records, operation) 
    {
        if(operation.wasSuccessful()) 
        {
            var tasksWithActualsCount = 0;

            Ext.Array.each(records, function(record) {
                if (record.get('Actuals') != null)
                {
                    tasksWithActualsCount++;
                }
            });

            var tasksCount = records.length;
            alert(tasksCount);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you using a version of AppSDK2 prior to rc1?

Comment: Yes. `<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0rc1/sdk.js"></script>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct- the important part is the limit: Infinity.

Unfortunately there seems to be a defect- Rally.data.WsapiDataStore is not passing the correct arguments to your callback function from the load call.  It's only passing the store instead of records, operation success.

This should get you by for now until the defect is fixed:

```
tasksWithActualsQuery.load({
    callback: function(store) {
        var tasksWithActualsCount = 0;

        store.each(function(record) {
            if (record.get('Actuals') != null) {
                tasksWithActualsCount++;
            }
        });

        var tasksCount = store.getTotalCount();
        alert(tasksCount);
    }
});
```